# Can I import Tensorflow with GPU if my compute ability is less than 3.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-8.1, nvidia

if your gpu doesnt have a compute ability of 3.0 or higher and you import tensorflow, what output will you get? Would tensorflow still import or what?

Answer (score 0):

`pip install tensorflow-gpu` should still function properly.

Just make sure to carefully read the output.

The worst case I'd imagine is that it will just not be as optimized as it could be given that tensorflow might be making assumptions about how many computations per second your machine can do.

After you install it, open a `python` environment and run this.

```
import tensorflow

I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
```

You should see output that's something like that. That's how you'll know if your GPU is being read properly. (if it's nvidia, I don't know about AMD.)

To find out which device is used you can run this

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

Answer (score -1):

To run on GPU, [the requirements are](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#optional_install_tensorflow_for_gpu_prerequisites)

> GPU card with CUDA Compute Capability 3.0 or higher.

However you can still run the CPU-only version of tensorflow.